# javascript infinite scroll with caching for performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser-cache

I'm trying to do infinite scrolling in javascript. the data is loaded from the server dynamically.

The problem is - every item in the table is heavy (charts and images), and when I load 20+ charts chrome uses around 1.5GB of ram.

Now, I know in android List view saves in memory only the visible elements and the rest is saved on disk(cache).

This is what I got right now:

```
function load_items(items){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).height() <= $(document).scrollTop() + 2 * $(window).height()) {
        populate(items);
    }
});
populate(items);}
function populate(items){
    $.post(
        "/feed_items",
        data={
            load: 15,
            loaded: items.children().length
        }, success=function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, item_data){
                var item = format_item(item_data); // return a div with the elements formatted inside
                $(items).append(item);
            });
    });
}
```

Does anybody knows a way to do it in javascript (+JQuery)? If there is a solution for react I can learn and use it too.

preferably, the solution would be an existing library, but If there is a way to implement it my self I would do it, I just don't know where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or do you expect a whole solution? Depending on your environment there are probably a lot of libraries and plugins ready for you to try out and maybe just inspect how they did it. You already stated the answer. Get the elements out of the DOM if they aren't visible.

Comment: If your webapplication makes Chrome use 1.5 GB of RAM after 19 ajax request, then you're probably doing something VERY wrong (memory leak?). Are you really sure, all 1.5 GB are caused by your site/app? (close chrome completely and reopen it in incognito mode)

Comment: I've tried the code above - that all it does is load more and more data without any kind of caching. I don't think I have memory leak, since the data I use is really heavy (interactive charts and iframes - I don't have an option right now not to use it, but I can cache them). 
I am asking now if anybody know a way to cache the items, or preferably a library that does caching.
Thank you for your comments